# SQL: Cannot delete or update parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

Whenever I try to delete a survey from table "survey" like this:

`DELETE FROM surveys WHERE survey_id = 77`

It prompts me an error stated below:

> #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ('user_surveys_archive', CONSTRAINT
>   'user_surveys_archive_ibfk_6' FOREIGN KEY ('user_access_level_id')
>   REFERENCES 'user_surveys' ('user_access_level_id') ON DELETE NO ACTION
>   )

First thing: I do not have any such table with this name "user_surveys_archive_ibfk_6"

2nd thing: There is no record of this survey in other tables.

Any idea on how can I delete this record of fix this issue?

**Edit**

This is the line I found when I export the table Constraints for table surveys

```
ALTER TABLE `surveys`
ADD CONSTRAINT `surveys_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`survey_type_id`) REFERENCES `survey_types` (`survey_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`
```

Comment: `user_surveys_archive_ibfk_6` is the name of the foreign key constraint, and generally can be absolutely anything you want - it's just a name, after all. it looks like an auto-generated one, so it's most likely in the `user_surveys_archive` table.

Comment: But there is no column in survey table with this title "user_access_level_id". Any idea on how to debug it?

Comment: maybe you broke the FK system by doing some `alter` queries with foreign_key_checks turned off. once the check is re-enabled, mysql won't scan the DB to verify all FKs are working, so you wouldn't have noticed until you tried a query which uses/refers to the now-nonexistent fields/tables.

Comment: Will this work if I turn OFF the foreign key constraints on these two tables? SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: it'll hide the error, since you've disabled the FK checking. it won't FIX the problem...

Comment: The foreign key on `surveys` is not the issue. You need to look at the foreign key on the **`user_surveys`** table. We expect that is going to be **`FOREIGN KEY (survey_id) REFERENCES surveys(survey_id) ON DELETE CASCADE`**, as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to first remove or update some rows in table **`user_surveys_archive`**.

Those rows are related to rows in the **`user_surveys`** table.

Likely, there's a foreign key constraint defined on table **`user_surveys`** that references rows in **`surveys`** you are attempting to delete.

(You'd need to check the foreign key definition, quickest way to get that is a

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE user_surveys
```

And look for `REFERENCES surveys`. (Likely, its a column named `survey_id`, but we're just guessing without looking at the definitions of the foreign key constraints.)

To find the rows in `user_surveys_archive` that are preventing the DELETE from happening...

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM user_surveys_archvive a
  JOIN user_surveys u
    ON u.user_access_level_id = a.user_access_level_id  
  JOIN surveys s
    ON s.survey_id = u.survey_id    -- change this to whatever the FK is
 WHERE s.survey_id = 77
```

It's likely that the foreign key constraint from `user_surveys` to `surveys` is defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  The attempt to delete rows from `surveys` identifies rows in `user_surveys` that should automatically be removed.

The attempt to automatically remove the rows from `user_surveys` is what's violating the foreign key constraint defined in `user_surveys_archive`. And that foreign key is *not* defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

(The other possibility is that there's a trigger defined that's doing some DML operations, but that would be odd.)

---

Once you identify the rows, you need to decide what changes to make to allow you to remove rows from `surveys`.

You can either DELETE the rows, or UPDATE them.

To delete the rows from `user_surveys_archive`, modify the query above and replace `SELECT` with `DELETE`.  If the `user_access_level_id` column in `user_surveys_archive` allows for NULL values, you can do an update.

Replace **`SELECT a.* FROM`** with **`UPDATE`**, and add **`SET a.user_access_level_id = NULL`** on a line above the `WHERE` clause...

```
UPDATE user_surveys_archvive a
  JOIN user_surveys u
    ON u.user_access_level_id = a.user_access_level_id  
  JOIN surveys s
    ON s.survey_id = u.survey_id    -- change this to whatever the FK is
   SET a.user_access_level_id = NULL
 WHERE s.survey_id = 77
```

---

(It seems strange to me that name of the foreign key column is `user_access_level_id`. But its just a column name, it could be named anything... seems odd to me because of the conventions and patterns that we follow in naming foreign key columns.)

Comment: can you please have a look at the edit I have just made? I guess you are very near on helping me resolve this issue.

Comment: The foreign key constraints defined on the **`surveys`** table is not the issue. What you need to look at is the foreign key constraint on the **`user_surveys`** table. We're expecting to see is **`(survey_id) REFERENCES surveys(survey_id) ON DELETE CASCADE`**. (We don't really care what the name of the constraint is.)

Comment: spencer7593 first of all +1 for writing all of that out. Also atif these are some useful queries that should help you to figure out the problem, but without us seeing the tables/fields and proper FK constraints there is a lot of assuming going on. You may have to adjust them slightly or make some tweaks, but his answer should help you resolve your problem.

Comment: @JKirkbride: Yes, there's a *lot* of assumptions going on, I hesitated to write an example query, because I'm just guessing, without seeing the actual table definitions. My answer neglected mentioning some other options... the foreign key constraint could be modified to include `ON DELETE CASCADE`, or it could be dropped altogether. But I think it's *important* that OP has a good understanding of what's going on, before we offer suggestions for changes to the schema.

Answer (score 3):

You should allow the foreign key to be ***NULL*** and then choose **ON DELETE  SET NULL**.

Personally I would recommend using both "ON UPDATE CASCADE" as well as "ON DELETE SET NULL" to avoid unnecessary complications, however your setup may dictate a different approach.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The `survey_id` of 77 must be referenced in a table possibly named `user_surveys_archive`. The error is saying the name of the foreign key restraint which is the `user_surveys_archive_ibfk_6`. If you need to delete `survey_id = 77` you will have to delete any child records or other records that reference it as a foreign key.

**Edit** After posting my answer I saw the comments above. atif the foreign key in the `user_surveys_archive` table may be named differently but still equal the value of 77 that you are trying to delete, and/or be referencing the `survey_id`. If that is not the case then there are some other problems within the database. You could try and look at the code for the FK to see how it was made and what fields it is referencing, or run a query to see if there are any records in the `user_surveys_archive` where the `user_access_level_id` is = 77.

**Edit 2** spencer7593's answer lays out how to run some of the queries mentioned in my answer.

Comment: What if I turn OFF foreign key check on these two tables: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: As mentioned above that won't solve the bigger problem only mask it and could have negative effects on the integrity of the data.